# Creating a batch file to backup data, and create a new directory to copy to each time it's run

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am needing to backup data, from the same spot each time, but to a newly created directory each time.  I have the part for creating new directories worked out, but how do I get the data to copy to the new directory, once it's created?

Here's what I have so far:

```
@echo off
set  counter=0
mkdir "c:\bginfo\dantest" 2>nul || goto :TryNext
:continue
rest of your code


goto :eof
:TryNext
set /a counter+=1
mkdir "c:\bginfo\dantest (%counter%)" 2>nul || goto :TryNext
goto :continue
```

Say the data is in `C:\Program\Data`, would I just do something like this:

```
copy c:\program\data\*.* c:\bginfo\dantest (%counter%)
```

I'm not sure how to code the newly created location.

Comment: Perhaps change the first `goto :TryNext` to `Call :TryNext`, then change `mkdir "c:\bginfo\dantest (%counter%)" 2>nul || goto :TryNext` to `MD "C:\bginfo\dantest (%counter%)" 2>NUL && GoTo :EOF`, and `goto :continue` to `GoTo TryNext`.

Comment: Please also be aware that there can be more than one reason why a make directory command fails. Your code seems to assume only that it will only fail due to an existing matching directory name. If there's another reason, such as a invalid path, or insufficient permissions, you will end up in a never-ending loop.

Comment: Thank you!  I'll give it a go and let you know.

Comment: BTW, for your copying, you'll need to use double-quotes around your destination path, _(as you did in your `mkdir`/`MD` command)_, and for best practice, you should double-quote all paths, e.g. `Copy /Y "C:\program\data\*.*" "C:\bginfo\dantest (%counter%)"`.